# Remove an installed plugin from krunner

Tags: kubuntu, krunner

I have Kubuntu 13.04 installed. I have recently installed a package of krunner pluging (plasma-runner-addons). It has some plugins for krunner but now I want to remove some of them (not all of them so I cant simply remove the package). And also I'm not going to disable them but I want to remove them.

How can I remove a special plugin from krunner???

(sorry for my bad english)

regards, mostafa

Answer (score 1):

Each plugin has a .desktop file in /usr/share/kde/services.  If you delete the .desktop file, then the plugin will no longer show up in krunner.

Additionally, the functionality of a plugin is provided by a library (.so) file in /usr/lib/kde4/, so you could also remove that.  You should know, however, that one library may provide functionality to more than one plugin.

For example, if you want to get rid of the YouTube plugin you could delete

- /usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-runner-youtube.desktop

And since no other plugin uses the library krunner_youtube, you could also delete

- /usr/lib/kde4/krunner_youtube.so

It's probably safer and easier to just leave it in place, though.

To reinstall a removed service, just reinstall the plasma-runners-addons package.

Having said all this, I think the preferred method of not having plugins is just to disable them.